# show category list bellow single product page

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I want to show products in same category withing  single product page. 
see bellow diagram what i want to achieve
[image: live site example] 
please see this site [https://www.jackthreads.com/goodale/shirts/rutledge-navywhite-plaid-shirt/products/170189][1] for more idea. i want to know how it achieve?

Comment: Relevant: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28659/random-products-from-same-category-with-parent-category-fill-up/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your view.phtml

```
<?php
$productId = $_product->getId();
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$catIds = $productCollection->getCategoryIds();
 foreach ($catIds as $categoryId) {
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
            foreach($_productCollection as $catProducts){
                echo    $catProducts->getName();
                echo '<br>';
                    // get your product here 
            }

}

?>
```

Comment: @Srinath  I have updated and tested my code it's working fine plz check it.

Comment: it gives fatal error getId()

Comment: Please use updated code

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this with below code..

```
    <?php $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $category_id; exit;
   $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
; //sets the order by price
} 

var_dump($products);?>
```

Comment: please give me some time to check it.

Comment: where i add view.pthml file or controller file

Comment: you can add in view.phtml

Comment: it give me null array  object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)#931 (32) { ["_cacheTag":protected]=> string(15) "catalog_product" ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(15) "catalog_product" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["_canAffectOptions":protected]=> bool(false) ["_typeInstance":protected]=> NULL ["_typeInstanceSingleton":protected]=> NULL ["_linkInstance":protected]=> NULL ["_customOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_urlModel":protected]=> NULL ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_optionInstance":protected]=> NULL

Comment: update the code and it is tested on view.phtml file..

Comment: it gives blank screen.i dont know why  i var_dump($cats) it gives categoriy ids but var_dump($products) it give blank screen

Comment: update and tested too ....

Comment: issue not solve but it can get category ids i dont know it is my issue.  i up voted answer   thank you helping

Answer (score 0):

The Magento way of doing this is to add related product for individual Product from admin Panel

`Catalog > Manage Products > Choose the Product to Edit > select the related Product tab > and choose the relevent Product(s) you want to show on Product Page`

I now it is time consuming Process but you can show more relevant products and increase the sales.