# Display (random) category products on single product view

Tags: magento2, product-view

I would like to display (random) products of the same category on a product view page.
Such that when you're at a product page, there are other products of the same category listed below.

I've Googled for 2 days now but can't find any solutions.

I guess we first need to get the current category and use that to get products from the database. However, I have no idea where to start or how to create a custom module/plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I did that for [magento-1.9](/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) with dynamic related products (upsells): [Random products from same category with parent category fill up](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28659/random-products-from-same-category-with-parent-category-fill-up/74186#74186)

Magento 2 still has the same event, `catalog_product_upsell`, so the code should be relatively easy to port.